# vim cut logical column from structured data

Tags: vim

I have some space delimited data that is structured into logical columns.

For example:

```
-71.12 0.150667281077312 0.002211111620961
-71.12 0.118496551977185 0.001861996157838
-71.12 0.060235544965347 0.002297217048708
-71.12 0.153327288481261 0.006010183052808
-71.12 0.124123948663225 0.002061072004207
-71.12 0.207259139445973 0.006717235817697
-60.96 0.157543582366536 0.002296431543423
-60.96 0.235150926363369 0.003101414303501
-60.96 0.259568965388604 0.00509310173342
-60.96 0.249144803559256 0.005918713226128
-60.96 0.293059928383778 0.004162901523096
-60.96 0.450566914005046 0.007136854816405
-50.8 0.750617196149124 0.009051035617119
-50.8 0.353984107758976 0.004572175646195
-50.8 0.528151230868303 0.007799510359974
-50.8 0.183651354357074 0.005641329790889
-50.8 0.41466714360944 0.005488604915895
-50.8 0.59927731014109 0.008919537503349
-40.64 0.535018719259586 0.006512021643672
-40.64 0.796646452506777 0.011224718752927
-40.64 0.484977557781429 0.006918056698062
-40.64 0.823404773156849 0.011420881130741
-40.64 0.723696626287657 0.008809901349382
```

I would like to separate the third column from the rest of the data.  I know it is possible to use a macro to do this.  A working example is:

`mbWWDGo<Esc>p'bj`

However, I wanted to know if there's a builtin way to cut and paste this as a single logical unit.  Blockwise selection won't do because the lines aren't regular.  Changing spaces into tabs seems like a good idea, but I also have some extremely short lines like:

```
0 1 0.012098302364638
```

So that won't necessarily work (unless I set my tabstop to something crazy).

Any ideas, or is a macro the best I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many alternative ways, but in term of typing effort, nothing will beat your macro. However, if you need this often, you can create a custom mapping or command (that can be recalled very quickly), and you'll benefit from a different implementation in terms of robustness and understandability.

- Temporarily remove the other columns, yank: `mb:%substitute/.*\s// | %yank | undo | 'bput`
- Filter the buffer as a string: `:put =map(getline(1, '$'), 'substitute(v:val, ".*\\s", "", "")')`

If you're willing to consider plugins, the [csv.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) has a `:CSVColumn` command.